# Socket io handle two different user types

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have two socket servers running on separate machine.

```
// Customers
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on(REQUEST, function (callback) {
        result = 'OK';
        callback(result);
    });
});

// Suppliers
// another socket server running on another instance

io.on('connection',function (socket) {

    socket.on(PRODUCTS, function (callback) {
        result = 'OK';
        callback(result);
    });
});
```

As i know I cannot emit from one server to another if I don't have mapping between two.

How can I differentiate two types of users on single socket server. ? (then we have unique socket id and doesn't need mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your problem. If you need to differentiate different users connected to the same socket you can use the concept of Rooms. If you need to offer different endpoints you can use namespaces.

I'll sum up here an example from the documentation:

### Rooms

You can call join to subscribe the socket to a given channel:

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room'); // At user login maybe you can decide if 
                            // the user should join the customer or suppliers
                            // room, or both if you need to
});
```

And then simply use **to** or **in** (they are the same) when broadcasting or emitting:

```js
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

To leave a channel you call leave in the same fashion as join.

Within each namespace, you can also define arbitrary channels that sockets can join and leave. Each connection join a default channel, useful to broadcasts, once you disconnect, your socketId will automatically leave any room he joined.

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
    // Useful to broadcast to every connected socket
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg); 
  });
});
```

### Namespaces

Basically we can define different endpoints, the default one is '/'.

#### Server side

When starting a server you can define many namepaces (endpoints) where your application can be reached. All of them may have different events and behaviours

```
var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected');
});
nsp.emit('hi', 'everyone!');
```

#### Client side

At the client side you must connect to the namespace you declared before

```
var socket = io('/my-namespace');
```

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Everything is one to one data transfer. But I need to validate the socket events for different types of user. Based on user type I have the logic. I dont like to simple check user types inside events.

Comment: inside namespace if i want to emit the event to specific user (other namespace user). how can I do ?  io.to(conId).emit('someEvent', data) ? Do I need to define namespace ?

Comment: I see, in that case I'll choose Rooms probably. You'll have to make the user join the customers or supplier room once he logs in, then he will emit generic events to the socket, and customer-specific events to the customer room. Same things for the suppliers. But you will have to check the user type to decide which room to join.

Comment: why rooms again? within namespace we can define events for each type of user and validate onconnection. ?

Comment: If I understood you requirements, you can choose between namespaces or rooms, personally I'll pick rooms in order to have only one endpoint and to have the ability to assign to the same user (admin i.e.) the events of both customers and suppliers just by making those users join both rooms. You can achieve this also with two endpoints (namespaces) I haven't yet tried this second option.

Answer (score 0):

Socket connection may take a parameter, assume its user_type. On the serverside you may get that parameter by:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var user_type =socket.handshake.query.user_type;
}
```

And on the client side you may initiate the connection like:

```
io.connect("<>"",{path:"/socket.io",query:"user_type=<your_user_type});
```

And then you may do whatever you want for different types of users. You may connect them for different rooms, or keep an hashmap to get information about which socketid belongs to which usertype

Comment: relying on client side usertype is not secure and recommended.

Comment: I really do not know what you mean by user_type. I just recommend to pass a parameter. Maybe you may pass a token from client-side to authenticate the user and get the related information by using that token.

Comment: yes, That way we can get the user type. How can I validate each events. ? Some events only belongs to user type 1 and others user type 2. ? I dont like the idea to check user type inside each event. Thats why asked the common setup to differentiate ?